# How default hook-delete-policy works in Helm 3?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart `myapp` with a job as pre-install and pre-upgrade hook.
That has [hook-deletion-policies](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hook-deletion-policies) mentioned as `before-hook-creation`.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "job-{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Release.Revision }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
        helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: post-install-job
        image: "alpine:3.3"
        command: ["/bin/sleep","{{ default "10" .Values.sleepyTime }}"]
```

As per the documentation, the job `job-myapp-1` should be removed during the second `helm upgrade`:

> before-hook-creation: Delete the previous resource before a new hook is
> launched (default)

But it is not being deleted. Whereas, the value `hook-succeeded` works as expected (deletes the job just after its successful completion).

Is there something wrong with the yaml or my understanding of how `before-hook-creation` works?

**Update:**

Keeping the annotation:

```
"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
```

Changed job name to avoid appending the release revision number:

```
name: "job-{{ .Release.Name }}"
```

This will generate the same job name on most of the releases.
Then the job gets replaced on the next `helm upgrade` and the pod associated with that previous job is also deleted.

However, the job will not be deleted on `helm uninstall` as the helm is not tracking those hook resources.

Answer (score 2):

If it fits your usecase, you can set the time to live field (`.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished`) on your job, so that it gets deleted automatically after a set time if it is successful:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/#cleanup-for-finished-jobs